# Check if anonymous customer already bought a specific product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce, orders

I want to mark not registered customers that already bought a product using either a cookie, a session variable, or some other way.

I have attempted it with the code below, but this approach doesn't seem to be working. In the first approach, I try to save something. Then, I try to get the session cookie already in use by woocommerce to save it in the database as a unique identifier. After, I can read it out of the database to see if it's a new unique user or not.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_payment_complete' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'so_payment_complete' );
function so_payment_complete( $order_id){
    setcookie('so_payment_complete',  1, time()+7200);
    WC()->session->set( 'so_payment_complete',true );

    $session = new WC_Session_Handler();
    $session_data = $session->get_session_data();
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/return_products.txt','cookies:'.(print_r($_COOKIE,true)) . "\n" ,FILE_APPEND );
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/return_products.txt','get_session_data:'.(print_r($session_data,true)) . "\n" ,FILE_APPEND );
}
```

It seems the cookie from `setcookie` never reaches the client. `WC()->session->set`  never reaches the database. `WC()->session->get` cannot get it on other pages either.

`$_COOKIE` and `$session_data` arrays are empty.

Comment: I found the reason why this fails:
This hook is triggered by the payment gateway server, not the client. 
So no client session cookies are available

Comment: Using the woocommerce_thankyou hook seems to be the only solution that does work